# Git branch name sometimes displayed in-line in terminal affecting the actual code?

Tags: linux, git, github, git-branch

So, I am working on a local repository that was cloned from the company GitHub project page.
Some times, when I open the terminal in the GitHub directory, in-line in my command line, the active branch name is displayed in green, inside parentheses (e.g. `tech@rdevice:~/projectxx (branch-name) $`
Now, the weird thing is that this does not always show up (unknown what triggers it) and apparently when it is not showing, I get errors when I am trying to compile the code which I don't get when the branch name is shown.

Does anyone what's going on here? As this is actively affecting my work I need to figure it out.

I tried deleting the repository and cloning it again with no luck, my colleagues observed a similar behavior on other machines. Maybe it is also worth mentioning that the repository has linked sub-directories to other repositories. Not sure if this has anything to do with the issue described here.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using zsh? (`echo $SHELL`)

Comment: nope, sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: When your shell prompt is configured to show the Git branch name, it will only do so if your current directory is inside of a Git repo. Also, when you're inside of a Git repo, it will show the branch name if you are on a branch, and a commit ID if you are detached.

Comment: Your shell prompt does not affect your code or repository content.